# Embed React Native app inside Android/iOS native app

Tags: react-native

I am currently investigating if it is possible to embed a RN app inside a existing Android and iOS app. The intended use, is that, based on user choice on app launch, the user will either use the existing native app, or use the RN app. The reason for this approach is to avoid having separate apps in stores.

There is no need for communication between RN app and native apps. I just want to start an RN generated activity(android) from my native apps, and therefore I believe I don't need to include the source for the RN app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little lost about RN. An app with RN is a native App that uses javascript code. it has its BundleID and the only way that the OS gives you permissions to access to the device and other things as notifications, GPS, Settings, etc, is registering as a separate app. You can also call an App (like an APP in RN) from a native app and viceversa.

If you ilustrate us the use case for your "embedded APP", would be great.